# how to disable another application broadcast receiver from my application in android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I need to disable outgoing call broadcast receiver for all the installed application in my mobile through my application. I tried but I didn't get it. please help me

**here is my code** :

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

    List<String> startupApps = new ArrayList<String>();
            final Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
            final List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryBroadcastReceivers(intent, 0);
            for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : activities) {
                ActivityInfo activityInfo = resolveInfo.activityInfo;
                if (activityInfo != null)
                    startupApps.add(activityInfo.name);
            }
            Log.e("receivers",startupApps.toString());

            for(int i=0;i<startupApps.size();i++)
            {
             if(!("com.example.customcalling.GetOutgoingNUmber1").equals(startupApps.get(i)))
             {
              String newreceivers=startupApps.get(i);
              Log.i("newReceivers", newreceivers);
              ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName("com.isodroid.fsci.controller.receiver","com.isodroid.fsci.controller.receiver.OutgoingCallReceiver");
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
          PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
          PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
             }
            }

    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"
      + phonenumber)));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. You have no rights to disable (or enabled) components of another app.